# Jags in .9.png buttons in Android!

Tags: android, user-interface, button

I am developing an Android app.
I have a custom button with a .9.png as background, it is perfect in the UI tool in Eclipse, shown here:

[image: button in Eclipse]

but on phone it's like this:

[image: button on a real device]

As you can see this is very jaggy(not sure I use the correct word)
and this is my 9-patch file:

[image: my 9-patch]

I know I can replace this simple button with an Shape XML drawable, but does anyone know what may be causing this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: I'm far from a graphics expert but it seems to me you need to create the buttons at a higher resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting your resource in `res/drawable-nodpi/`, or possibly `res/drawable/`, instead of wherever it is, and see if that helps. As @MisterSquonk suggests, I think this is Android applying automatic density scaling.

Comment: Thank you, I solved this by moving my resources from /res/drawable to /res/drawable-hdpi, Android seems to default the dpi to medium or low, that's why I have this problem!